# Add a missing table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I miss a table in my data model
I have an existing DB, and tried:
[EF Power Tools like THIS description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)

tables:

- User (Id, ...)
- Project (ID, Name,..)
- Timestamp (ID,Start, End, UserID, ProjectID..)

But I have no Table "Poject_Favorit" (UserId, ProjectID)

So I write the Table myself:

```
public class Project_Favorite
{
    [Key]public Guid GuidUser { get; set; }
    public Guid GuidProject { get; set; }
}
```

and I added:

```
public DbSet<Project_Favorite> Project_Favorite { get; set; }
```

to my DbContext

EF searched for "dbo.Project_Favorite" but it should search for "Timeworx.Project_Favorite"

so I added:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Project_FavoriteMap());
```

to my DbContext

and created the file "Project_FavoriteMap.cs:

```
class Project_FavoriteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project_Favorite>
{
    public Project_FavoriteMap() { 
        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.GuidProject);
        this.HasKey(t => t.GuidUser);

        this.ToTable("Project_Favorite", "Timeworx");
    }        
}
```

Now there is an error. It says "...Project_Favorite already defined..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Poject_Favorit` table is a many-to-many join between `User` and `Project`. In that case you don't need a corresponding entity class. Your `User` class will probably have an `ICollection<Project>` and your `Project` class will probably have an `ICollection<User>`. That represents a many-to-many hierarchy. A project can favorited by many users and a user can favorite many projects. Hence the two collections.